# type code 'CustomerCouponForPromotionSourceRule' invalid in Spartacus setup

Tags: angular, solr, spartacus-storefront

### Environment Details

- Spartacus:  1.5.4
- OS: Windows 10 - v1809 - 8 GB ram - 500GB hard disk
- Other environment details: Angular 8/JAVA 1.11 - SAP Commerce Suite 1905.13

### What I am trying to do

- Following the documentation to setup the Spartacus along with the SAP Commerce Suite 1905.13 (https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud/) using the sampledataaddon given in this repository for the version 1.5.4.
- Successfully initialized the spartacus installer recipe (step 13 in the docs).
- I try to do step 14 in the docs. I initially get an error in between saying that `customerCouponCodeValueResolver` bean is not available, like in https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/5662.
- Installed the `customercouponoccaddon` as suggested.
- Do an `ant clean all` and try step 14 again.

### Observed Results

A error shows up in between.

```
ERROR [solr indexer thread] [FlexibleSearch] Flexible search error occured...
ERROR [solr indexer thread] [FlexibleSearch] Query translation was not successful.
ERROR [solr indexer thread] [DefaultIndexerWorker] [Indexer worker 0 (UPDATE index operation on electronicsIndex/Product)] failed to process index items due to Failed to index item with PK 8796220293121: Failed to resolve values for item with PK: 8796220293121, by resolver: customerCouponCodeValueResolver, for properties: [customerCouponCode], reason: type code 'CustomerCouponForPromotionSourceRule' invalid
de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: Failed to index item with PK 8796220293121: Failed to resolve values for item with PK: 8796220293121, by resolver: customerCouponCodeValueResolver, for properties: [customerCouponCode], reason: type code 'CustomerCouponForPromotionSourceRule' invalid
```

and also the command keeps on executing without finishing.

### Additional Information

I actually do not how to get around this. Any solution for this is much appreciated. The goal is to setup the sampledataaddon in their repository but it seems fail internal.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have commented on this previously in the feedback channel in the Spartacus Slack, but that isn't easy to find via search ... so I will repeat it here:

In the installation instructions, I think it should really also be asking people to add extName customercouponoccaddon & then also adding that addon into the list in

```
forStoreFronts('ycommercewebservices') {
    names 'acceleratorwebservicesaddon', 'consignmenttrackingoccaddon', 'customerinterestsoccaddon', 'notificationoccaddon', 'cmsoccaddon'
    template 'ycommercewebservices'
}
```

Currently the spartacussampledataaddon has several solr.impex files that assume that customercouponservice is included in the Commerce build to provide customerCouponCodeValueProvider, but nothing in the b2c_acc_plus recipe seems to include it currently.  Adding in the customercouponoccaddon as above should resolve this.

Comment: ya actually that did fix the issue, but at the same time, I had to initialize the entire system, to get rid of the issue. Is there a way to resolve it with out re-initializing the app via the recipe. The reason why I'm asking this is because, I have a windows setup, and the initialize process itself takes too long (like 3 hrs). So if you know any other way to resolve it. That is much appreciated.